# Android Studio virtual device emulator crashes my laptop(HP Spectre x360)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, device-driver

Whenever I run **Android Studio (version 4.2.2) with the Virtual Device Emulator**, my computer crashes. I’m using Expo CLI to run my (very basic)React Native App on the emulator. The crashes happen every single time I use the emulator, triggered by random things: mainly when I have an error in my code or when I try to use features like the screen recorder, sometimes when I’m not even running my code. Frequency and sensitivity to crashing from code errors(or for no reason) seems to increase after each crash. I can use it for longer durations after I’ve given my computer a break over night.

There are 3 stop codes that I get:

- VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE
- DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
- DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

I have tried every solution I can think of. I’ve called HP hardware support and they’ve verified that my computer is up to date with all the drivers and BIOS updated. I’ve also subscribed (For $50!) to HP Smart Friends and they’ve tried uninstalling the NVIDIA GPU, which seemed to work for a few hours just using the Intel GPU. But after using it for an hour or two, it started crashing consistently again. I’ve also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android studio.

Here is a picture of what the Android studio SDK Tools configuration:
[image of config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gowOn.png)

My Laptop is an **HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15t-eb000**
Here are some relevant specs of my laptop:

- 256 GB PCIe® NVMe™ M.2 SSD
- Windows 10 Home 64 ADV
- 6-cell, 72.9 Wh Li-ion polymer
- **Intel® Core™ i7-10510U (1.8 GHz, up to 4.9 GHz, 8 MB L3 cache, 4 cores) + NVIDIA® GeForce® MX330 (2 GB) + 16 GB Memory**

Relevant Windows features turned on:

- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor Platform

In the BIOS: **“Virtualization Technology”** feature is enabled

Here is a picture of **Windows Error reporting** from the last few days:
[image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTB2k.png)

Answer (score 1):

`VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE` and `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` sound alike driver issues (one can look them up), but `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION` appears to be an hardware issue, eg. reaching thermal threshold.

You'd need to install the according GL drivers for that [GeForce MX330 GPU](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). Beside those irrelevant Windows features you've listed, only [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm) matters (which can be installed with the SDK manager).

And if it crashes after a few hours with software renderer (which that Intel GPU might use), this machine might well have a general thermal problem... which usually do tend to become more obvious when the summer is about to begin; keeping an eye on the thermal sensor suggested.